# What's the best practice for running a "singleton process"?

Tags: linux, operating-system, child-process

So let's say I want to have a local server process, which is responsible for synchronizing a dataset which is shared between several processes running on the same system.

I don't want the server to run all the time, it should only run when needed, until it reaches a natural termination point.

So the desired behavior would be:

1. Client process runs
2. Client process attempts to query the server
3. If the server is not running, the client process starts it and connects
4. If the server is already running, the client simply connects
5. There should only ever be one process of this type running, so if two clients reach step 2 at the same time, only one server will be launched

What is the best way to manage a process which must behave in this manor?

Comment: mutex, test, start if needed, unmutex

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/daemonize